# Responsive image with text overlay

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a grid where the images have an overlay on hover, containing text.

However, I can't seem to do this AND have responsive issues.

I've tried removing the fixed heights but this just causes the grids to loose their sizing all together. I have tried tables and absolute positioning without any joy.

Test site is [here.](http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/)

The markup is:

```
<div class="work-item clickable">

    <a href="http://localhost:8888/work-example-client-name-11/"></a>

    <div class="front">
        <img width="460" height="380" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    </div>

    <div class="back">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
section#homepage .content article .work-item {
    cursor: pointer;
     border-right: 20px solid #fff;
     border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
    width: 33.33%;
}

section#homepage .content article .work-item .front {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

section#homepage .content article .work-item .back {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 25;
    position: absolute;
}

section#homepage .content article .work-item .back .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I checked your website. Your .work-item each have a parent item which is an article tag. First you have to make sure that these are creating a grid not the .work-item. Delete the float in .work-item and put it in the article tag its CSS because they have to be next to each other… I you want the article tag to wrap around its content use overflow:auto; in its CSS.

Comment: Of coarse the width:33.333% will go into the article tag its CSS aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example layout, based on your example, which includes overlapping text on hover of an image.

The [`<figure>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) seems good for this. It needs an image and a `<figcaption>`. Let's wrap it in an anchor tag so the entire image is clickable:

```
<a>
    <figure>
        <img />
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
```

#### The CSS

- The anchor element can line up the images. The width is 33.33% so that there are 3 images to a row. The images can be spaced with some padding here as well:

  ```
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  ```
- The figure is made `position: relative` so that the `position: absolute` figcaption is positioned relative to it. This will ensure that the text is layered over the image. We can center it vertically with `top: 50%` and the transform to offset it correctly:

  ```
  figure {
    position: relative; 
  }

  figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0; 
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  ```
- The image takes up the entire width of its parent:

  ```
  figure img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  ```

#### Full example

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-width: 600px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
figure:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}
figcaption h2 {
  font-size: 3vw;
}
figcaption p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
figure:hover:before,
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a><a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a><a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a><a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a><a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a><a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>More text here, plenty of space</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

**Text size:** The text can be made to re-size to suit the image width using `vw` as a `font-size`.

**Image size:** Place a min width on the body so that the images don't get too small.

**Overlay background:** This is provided with the `figure:before` element.

**Note:** The `<a>` elements have no whitespace between them, [this prevents an inline gap.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) The `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates padding and borders into the width and height calculation.

Comment: Thanks this worked great, appreciate the comments too :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could rethink your html structure about links and images, and play with absolute positionning for either image or title.

example:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.work-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 1em;
}

a {
  display: inline-table;
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s
}

figcaption:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 92%;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-cell;
}

figure:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}

figcaption h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin: 0 -2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img width="460" height="380" src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img   src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img width="460" height="380" src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img width="460" height="380" src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img   src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="work-item clickable">
  <a href="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/work-example-client-name-12/">
    <figure>
      <img width="460" height="380" src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/Testing/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000-460x380.jpg" class="attachment-work-featured-image size-work-featured-image" alt="stock-photo-4772348-1500x1000" />
      <figcaption>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joepdooper/3NSP8/78/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8311/8023199579_f52f648727_m.jpg"></div>
  <div class="overlay">Text</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8311/8023199579_f52f648727_m.jpg"></div>
  <div class="overlay">Text</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8311/8023199579_f52f648727_m.jpg"></div>
  <div class="overlay">Text</div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  width: 33.333%;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.outer .inner {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.outer .inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.outer .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:pink;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}

.outer:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Your outer would be of coarse your article tag