# Having difficulty adding blockquote on image properly

Tags: html, css

I am working on learning the css, html skills and trying to put quote on the image but only half of the quote is covering the image.I have tried adding the top, bottom but that's not working. After adding margin to the css, the text is coming but only half.

Like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFgza.png)

```
body{
    text-align: center;
}

#img{
position: relative;

}

#quote{
    font: 2em/1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: block; 

    margin: -180px 0 1px 0;
    color: #fff;
}

<div class="lazCat">
        
        <span id="show"></span>
        <img id="img" src="normalTime.jpg">
    <span id="quote">Let's have some lunch!</span>
    </br>
    <label for="wakeup-time" id="lab">
        <b>SET WAKE UP TIME</b>
        </label>
        <select id="wakeup-time" name="wakeup">
            <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
            <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question would be more meaningful with the corresponding HTML

Comment: Try adding HTML or an image of what you want to reproduce.

Comment: This is the problem `margin: -180px 0 1px 0;` use the `top/left/right/bottom` properties to align the quote properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325961/responsive-image-with-text-overlay

Comment: Added the html and the image of what is happening right now. Thanks!

Comment: It's working now after adding below to the css and replacing margin with auto.  Any other suggestions?                                                               
       margin: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 30%;